# Junit : How to mock a private method using Mockito or how to get coverage without mocking the private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

```
public List<String> fetchNodes(MultipartFile file, String content, String fileType) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<String> parentNodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    transformDataMap(file, content, fileType, map, null, parentNodes);
    return parentNodes;
}
```

whete MultipartFile is an Interface and transformDataMap is a private method.

```
   @InjectMocks
private FileViewerService fileViewerService;

@Mock
private MultipartFile multipartfile;

@Test
public void test_fetchNodes() throws Exception {
    
    String content = "content";
    String fileType = "TXT";
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree("{ \"json\":\"xyz\"}");
    map.put("nodemap",(Object)jsonNode.asText());
    Mockito.when(multipartfile.getOriginalFilename()).thenReturn("test.txt");
    
    List<String> parentNodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    parentNodes.add("parentnode1");
    parentNodes.add("parentnode2");
    
     Mockito.when(fileViewerService.fetchNodes(ArgumentMatchers.any(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(parentNodes);

    List<String> resultPNodes = fileViewerService.fetchNodes(multipartfile, content,fileType);
    assertEquals(parentNodes, resultPNodes);

}
```

this is my code. I am getting error in junit when Mocking the service class using Mockito saying I cannot use ArgukmentMatchers outside stubbing.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Mockito. You test private methods by testing the methods that use them.

Comment: If you mock the method that you’re testing, then it only tests the mock and won’t provide any coverage of the class.

Comment: what is the alternative then ? @TimMoore

Comment: @isagirl -> test the methods that use that private method, for each scenario of that private method

Comment: @isagirl you should remove this line: `Mockito.when(fileViewerService.fetchNodes(ArgumentMatchers.any(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(parentNodes);`. As a general guideline, rather than designing tests around mocking, or even around coverage reports, it’s best to start by asking: “how do I specify the behaviour of this method?” Mocking can be useful to do this, but it is only a tool for assisting in the specification of the tested class’s interactions with _other_ classes. And it’s not always the best tool for this. What does this method actually do?

Comment: More specifically, I agree with Stultuske. You want your test to be calling the private method (indirectly). The `fetchNodes` method doesn’t really do much other than call `transformDataMap`. You can’t usefully test the former without indirectly testing the latter.

Comment: This is often a reason to make methods package-private instead of private. Test classes are usually in the same package, so they have access to these methods. But in this case I agree with what others have said - `fetchNodes` isn't actually doing anything so you can test `transformDataMap` by testing `fetchNodes`.

Comment: Please show your `transformDataMap() method` because of more potential mock candidates.

Answer (score 0):

Your test code should test the `fetchNodes()` method according to the name of the test. Therefore it does not make any sense to mock this same method, otherwise you would only test, if the Mockito library works as expeced, and if you test setup code works  which is probably not what you are trying to achieve. The only thing here, which could make sense to test, would be transformDataMap(), because this seems to be the only non-trivial part in your  `fetchNodes()` method. So apearently you just need to delete the line `Mockito.when(fileViewerService...` and you are good.